# Stop All Timers in Lua (Garry's Mod)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Hello how to stop all the timers that are already launched?

I do not know how to do that so it would be nice if you could help me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a timer you store its unique identifier in a list.

Then you iterate over the list and call timer.stop for every identifier.

Comment: OK but the timers I want to quit on are random names

Comment: @BXEE who is creating those timers if not you?